# How to get immediate child in less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to assign CSS to the immediate child of an element in less. I know about the > solution. But in my case I am not sure about what the element is or what class it has...i just want to get the immediate child and apply style. Like we get the first child though we dont know what that is or similarly the last child.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You should add a class, _anything_ to functionally identify it. Otherwise you're not being semantic in your styles.

Comment: @VijetaShetty css code?

Comment: @gustavohenke yes that could be one solution...assigning a class to all immediate child elements... but isnt there a way without this?

Comment: @MridulaTripathi if I understood you right, you don't know who the parent is. This way you should assign a class; if you don't know who the children are, then you may use the solution by MildlyInteresting

Comment: if i assign a class i would be able to do so like this .selector{.someclass{somestyle}} in LESS... but i don have an option to assign class as of now...so i was looking for an alternate solution to replace "someclass" with something like "first child" "last child" "nth child" in normal CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by immediate child you mean any element in the first level below some other element, what about this?

```
div > * {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74H6y/

Of course, if you did not define styles for the lower elements, some properties are set to `inherit` by default and you'll get unwanted results.

Comment: @MridulaTripathi: It's not. Unless your values are default (which is `inherit` for a bunch of properties). But whatever other solution would be affected by this as well.

Comment: i was working with less notation... :) and i tried with '*' there it doesn't work... I will try and check may be I am missing something or may the default value problem that you mentioned...thanks anyways

Comment: That's weird. I just tried and it works perfectly for me. *(I don't see why it shouldn't, either. Valid CSS is also valid LESS)* Are you using an outdated browser that might not support this?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a CSS style in your LESS code, and then using JavaScript identify the root element and then set this style on to that element.

Without knowing either a parent element / id / styleClass - I am not sure how you will achieve it.

Comment: i will try to apply a class to every element thats added to my div and apply style to it.